# Responsive height of div issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height

One example is better than a thousand words, so here you go:

https://jsfiddle.net/jesuxapo/os53cyc1/

As you can see, the height is responsive, but not completely. The problem is the `<div id="k">` with fixed `height` of `150px`. Try to play with it and I think you'll understand exactly what I mean. I want to get rid of this 'problem' somehow.

I could use the `calc()` of the `css3`, however it's not cross-browser(especially android and IE8-9).

Perhaps there's some other solution for this using html and css languages?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the display:table properties (IE8 and later):https://jsfiddle.net/os53cyc1/1/

it will grow if content is more than 100vh all together

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
body {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
body>div {
  display:table-row;
}
div {
  border: solid 2px #FFFF00;
}
div#a {
  position: relative;
  background: #800000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div#b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
div#c {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
div#k {
  height: 150px;
  background: #008000;
}
```

```html
<div id="k">
Hello, I'm K and I just broke your code
</div>
<div id="a"><br><br><br><br>
This is relative div with height of 100% and max-height of 500px
<div id="b">
This div is aligned to the top of the Red div
</div>
<div id="c">
This div aligned to bottom of the Red div
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but perhaps there's a better way without using tables? I really don't like it.

Comment: @jesuxapo display has other options(but flex is not avalaible for IE8) , **and do not mixe HTML and CSS , these are div with display and not HTML tables. (li are display:list-item by defaut, div is block , span is inline ... but thats only styling not semantics**